# React-Native: How to access react-native app's permissions in Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to access my react-native app's specific permissions in Android. I can access and pull up my app's info page in Android, but I can't go directly into the permissions screen from my app.

I am using react-native-android-open-settings to to achieve this. By using this I am able to access the app's info page, but can't access the specific permissions page for the app without the user having to click on permissions in App Info. The library can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-open-settings

```js
import AndroidOpenSettings from 'react-native-android-open-settings'
```

```js
  async goToSettings() {

    if(Platform.OS === 'android') {
      AndroidOpenSettings.appDetailsSettings()
    } else {


      Linking.canOpenURL('app-settings:').then(supported => {
        if (!supported) {
          console.log('Can\'t handle settings url');
        } else {
          return Linking.openURL('app-settings:');
        }
      }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
    }
  }
```

The expected result is for it to open the permissions page and not the app info page.

Comment: Hi @Sebastttian S. I am facing this issue. Did you found anything?